# Creating nested JSON from API call response

Tags: go

How can I create a nested JSON response from a response I received from an API?

For example, I got a `resp` (`*http.Response`) from an API which I expect to be a list of objects (`[{},{},{},...]`)

I want to create a response like so

```
{
  total: 1234,
  addresses: [{},{},{}]
}
```

I'm not quite sure how to deal with this. I got close as my code below returns a similar structure but my `addresses` section returns an escaped string like so

`"[{\"access\":\"INTERNAL\",\"address\":\"1P9SnpTait5bS\"}]"`

```
func (h *Handler) getAddresses(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    type Message struct {
        Total     int `json:total`
        Addresses  string `json:addresses`
    }

    resp, _ := h.Search(address, page, pageOffset)   // *http.Response
    body, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)

    res := Message{
        Total:     total,
        Addresses: string(body),
    }
    m, _ := json.Marshal(res)
    w.Write(m)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your desired response format, `Addresses` should be defined as type `[]map[string]interface` rather than of type `string`.

```
    type Message struct {
        Total      int `json:total`
        Addresses  []map[string]interface{} `json:addresses`
    }
```

Then you would json unmarshal the response bytes into a temporary variable of type `[]map[string]interface{}` before assigning the temporary variable to `Message.Address`, and finally json marshal `Message` as you were doing already.

Your question currently doesn't demonstrate where `total` is coming from. I assume you know how to deal with `total`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`json.RawMessage`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#RawMessage) if all you need is to pass the json along.

```golang
func (h *Handler) getAddresses(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    type Message struct {
        Total     int             `json:"total"`
        Addresses json.RawMessage `json:"addresses"`
    }

    resp, err := h.Search(address, page, pageOffset) // *http.Response
    if err != nil {
        w.WriteHeader(http.StatusInternalServerError)
        return
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()

    body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    if err != nil {
        w.WriteHeader(http.StatusInternalServerError)
        return
    }

    res := Message{
        Total:     total,
        Addresses: json.RawMessage(body),
    }
    if err := json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(res); err != nil {
        log.Println("failed to respond with json:", err)
    }
}
```